# Python 3 Paho-MQTT Published/Subscribed JSON message won't parse

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, mqtt, paho

Rookie here.

I have a simple python code that's supposed to subscribe to a topic and publish JSON payload to the same topic using MQTT protocol. But for some reason, I am unable to load the payload as JSON!

What am I doing wrong here?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json
mqtt_broker      = '192.168.1.111'
mqtt_topic_one   = 'mqtt_topic/tops_one'
mqtt_topic_two   = 'mqtt_topic/tops_two'

json_data_1      = '''{
    "this_json": "info",
    "data": {
        "multi_keyval": {
            "1": "1",
            "5": "5",
            "15": "15"
        },
        "single_keyval": {
            "single_key": "200"
        }
    }
}'''


def pass_to_func_and_pub(data_to_pub):
    print(data_to_pub)                # --------> This PRINTS
    print(json.loads(data_to_pub))    # --------> This DOES NOT PRINT

    # The following two lines don't work either.
    unpacked_json = json.loads(data_to_pub)
    client.publish(mqtt_topic_two, unpacked_json['this_json'])


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    client.subscribe(mqtt_topic_one)
    client.publish(mqtt_topic_one, json_data_1)


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    pass_to_func_and_pub(str(msg.payload))

client = mqtt.Client()

client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.connect(mqtt_broker)
try:
    client.loop_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    client.disconnect()
    print('MQTT client disconnected, exiting now.')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here.

### 1. Exception handling

You're not handling exceptions (and Paho effectively ignores them within handlers, to keep the client alive I guess). This means when the exception *is* thrown in `json.loads(data_to_pub)`, you're never seeing this but the function is exited as there is no local `except` block.

#### Improved version

```
def pass_to_func_and_pub(data_to_pub):
    print("Raw data: ", data_to_pub)
    try:
        unpacked_json = json.loads(data_to_pub)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Couldn't parse raw data: %s" % data_to_pub, e)
    else:
        print("JSON:", unpacked_json)
        client.publish(mqtt_topic_two, unpacked_json['this_json'])
```

#### Hang on, what exception?

Running this improved version we can now see:

`Couldn't parse raw data: b'{\n    "this_json": "info",\n    "data": {\n        "multi_keyval": {\n            "1": "1",\n            "5": "5",\n            "15": "15"\n        },\n        "single_keyval": {\n            "single_key": "200"\n        }\n    }\n}' Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

*Hmmm, what's that `b'` doing there?*...

### 2. The encoding problem

Essentially your problem comes down to one line

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    pass_to_func_and_pub(str(msg.payload))
```

By calling `str` on the `payload` of that `MqttMessage`, **which is a `bytes` object** in Python 3, you'll get the stringified version of those bytes, e.g. `b'foobar'`.

This `b`, of course, makes it invalid JSON now, hence `Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`...

#### Fixed version

Don't call `str`! [Json.loads can handle `bytes` too](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads). So:

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    pass_to_func_and_pub(msg.payload)
```

Or, assuming utf-8 encoding, we can do this more explicitly (I prefer working in strings):

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    pass_to_func_and_pub(msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is answer's wonderful and worked perfectly!  Thank you so much.  I didn't realize that Paho ignores exceptions within handlers.

Comment: Great! Glad it helped