# Expecting value: line 1,column1 (char 0) with Python JSON

Tags: python, json, simplejson

I'm currently trying to decode some data sent over PAHO MQTT using the simplejson (or just json) library.

```
Got message <paho.mqtt.client.MQTTMessage object at 0x7f1e500432e8>
b'{"timestamp": "2019-06-24T14:34:25+02:00", "data": "14:34:25.791022 close(74)               = 0\\n", "processname": ""}'
Error in on_message
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I can't wrap my head around why json would not decode this string.

Here's the part that throws the error:

```
def on_message(self,client,userdata,msg):
        """MQTT Callback function for handling received messages"""
        print("Got message {0}".format(str(msg)))
        datadict = simplejson.loads(msg.payload)

        temp = self.parse(datadict['data'])
```

msg.payload obviously is a byte string as seen in the output above, what is missing? Why doesn't that work?

Thanks a lot in advance

---

EDIT:
I think this has something to do with the b before the string, because this works just fine:

```
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import simplejson
>>> data = simplejson.loads('{"timestamp": "2019-06-24T14:34:25+02:00", "data": "14:34:25.791022 close(74)               = 0\\n", "processname": ""}')
>>> print(type(data))
<class 'dict'>
>>>
```

Comment: Please post the full traceaback whenever you get an exception.

Comment: @Guillaume This is everything the python interpreter gave me. This is a multithreaded program and does not produce more output than that for some reason.

Comment: Hi, I tried the bytestring (with the 'json' module) and that gets converted just fine. How about you try something like `datadict = simplejson.loads(str(msg.payload))`. Or use the `json` module.

Comment: @GiacomoCasoni I tried that already but that doesnt seem to work too.

Comment: Did you also try `datadict = simplejson.loads(str(msg))`? After all that is what you're printing.

Comment: Yes. msg is a MQTT Message object so we have to access the payload in order to get the string.

Comment: I think it's hard to help without more insights on the code, maybe check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53334451/python-3-paho-mqtt-published-subscribed-json-message-wont-parse

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly my problem!

Answer (score 0):

This thread handled exactly my problem.

It seems like the MQTT handlers supress warnings and exceptions which is why I couldn't retrieve the stacktrace.
[Python 3 Paho-MQTT Published/Subscribed JSON message won't parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53334451/python-3-paho-mqtt-published-subscribed-json-message-wont-parse)